# What are reasons that read() on a POSIX serial port might be slow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded, posix, embedded-linux

I'm writing a console application under Ubuntu that uses the serial port. It needs to read and write from the serial port at 60 Hz.

I find that the call to read() is often, but not always, slow. I have set O_NDELAY, so often it returns immediately (great). Sometimes it takes up to 50 ms to finish, and that is too slow for my application. Before calling read(), I check the number of chars available, so it should not be waiting for data.

What is read() doing that takes so long? How can I speed it up?

Options on the port are:

```
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;

options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
options.c_iflag &= ~IXON;

options.c_oflag = 0;
```

edit: I'd been using select() earlier but it turned out to be orthogonal to the question. Updated with my latest information.

Comment: What is the baud rate on that serial port? Perhaps the kernel need to read at least one whole byte...

Comment: It could simply be that your particular piece of hardware requires (e.g. hardware specs say so), or imposes (e.g. lame USB devices) on the OS to obtain its status.

Comment: @jørgensen: How would I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the low_latency flag on the serial port.

See [High delay in RS232 communication on a PXA270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667141/high-delay-in-rs232-communication-on-a-pxa270)
and
http://osdir.com/ml/serial/2003-11/msg00020.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not what `select` is doing, it's what the system is doing. Your thread eventually uses up its timeslice and the system allows other code to run. If you use a sensible timeout, rather than trying to return immediately, the system should treat your process as interactive and the delays should go away.

If there's a point to `select`ing on a single descriptor with a `0` timeout, I can't figure out what it is. Why not just try the operation and see if you get a `EWOULDBLOCK` error?

Why not use a sensible timeout so the system lets other processes run when you have nothing to do?

Comment: I removed the select(), as you are correct it is not necessary. What you don't see is that I have a processor yield elsewhere in the code. I was using usleep() for this, but I'm looking into whether the high resolution timers are better. I can't block on the read because I've got things to broadcast whether or not there is something to read.

Comment: So figure out how long it is until your next broadcast and block in `select` for that long. This will work much better than `usleep`.

Comment: Then you probably forgot to set the descriptor non-blocking.