# periodic serial port latency

Tags: serial-port, latency

I am reading data from a sensor connected to a standard RS-232 serial port on a conventional linux kernel (Ubuntu 12.04)

The sensor outputs at 1000Hz.  And connects at a baud rate of 115200, 8N1.  Each sensor reading is 4 bytes, for a total throughput of 4Kb/s.   The pattern of transmission, confirmed by oscilloscope, is a 4-byte burst followed by a near-millisecond pause.   The sensor is very, very consistent.

> 99% of the packets are received with very low latency.  However for about 0.5% of the bytes, the serial port read blocks for 2-8ms.   Following this block, all the "missed" bytes are read very quickly.  This suggests data is, on rare occasions,  being buffered.

I have experimented with scheduler priority (nice) and serial port settings (ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY, VMIN, VTIME, raw, non-blocking settings, etc.).    None of these seem to have any discernible effect.

Is there anything else I can do to get more consistent serial port reads short of recompiling the kernel or switching to a more real-time OS?

Comment: *"This suggests data is, on rare occasions, being buffered"* -- Each byte is always buffered (typically twice).  The **read()** syscall fetches bytes from a buffer, not directly from the UART's register or FIFO.

Comment: Correct.   I meant in the context of bytes being queued more quickly than they're being read.   My assertion is that 1ms should be more than enough time for read() to pull a byte off that buffer, while I'm seeing that it takes 2-8ms on occasion during which the buffer is growing.

Comment: Some of it is very Atmel ARM specific, but maybe there's something useful from https://www.at91.com/viewtopic.php?t=21497

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be provided with software or hardware arguments. See for example [High delay in RS232 communication on a PXA270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667141/high-delay-in-rs232-communication-on-a-pxa270) or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96893/what-can-i-do-to-decrease-the-latency-from-these-serial-ports-which-are-attached.You can try to use low_latency paramlow_latency parameter how is suggest in [Minimize Linux Serial Port Latency](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/06/minimize-linux-serial-port-latency/).

Comment: Thank you, but per my post, I've already tried ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY, both through setserial or through code, to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when reading to the serial port on my Jetson AGX Orin. I actually tried the PREEMPT rt patch and set the read thread to real-time priority. Most of the time the latency of `read()` is around 200 us, but occasionally it jumps to 2-4 ms.

I also tried `ASYNC_LOW_LATENCY` flag, but that doesn't change the results.

[Latency Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXopV.png)